# Using crypto to sign and verify strings

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

I'm playing around with Node's Crypto's [generateKeyPairSync](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypairsync_type_options), [Sign](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_sign) and [Verify](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_verify) but I can't get this ridiculously simple code to work: `verify.verify` always output false, eventhough it should output true. What am I missing?

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const txt = 'Some text to sign';

// generates asymmetric key pair
const keys = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 4096,
    publicKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'pkcs1',
        format: 'pem'
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'pkcs1',
        format: 'pem',
    }
});

// generates a signature object
const sign = crypto.createSign('sha256');
sign.update(txt);

// generates a verify object
const verify = crypto.createVerify('sha256');
verify.update(txt);

// should logs true, but logs false
console.log(
    verify.verify(
        keys.publicKey,
        sign.sign(keys.privateKey, 'base64')
    )
);
```

Comment: It is always easier to understand and debug without compound statements. Use a variable for the signed data so you can see it. It looks like signing Base64 encodes the output but the Base64 signing is not Base64 decoded.

Comment: Yup, that's what Nino Filiu noticed (see answer below). But thanks for the tip on compound statements @zaph!

Answer (score 2):

You can precise `signature_format: "latin1" | "hex" | "base64"` as the third argument of `verify.verify`. This returns `true`, as expected:

```
verify.verify(
    keys.publicKey,
    sign.sign(keys.privateKey, 'base64'),
    'base64'
)
```

Comment: Correct and it would be more clear as two statements: `signed = sign.sign(keys.privateKey, 'base64')` and `match = verify.verify(
    keys.publicKey, signed, 'base64')`. It is  clearer that each has a Base64 argument.